# Maior número ímpar

Tags: c, array

Passei horas tentando resolver, comecei a achar que o problema pode ser no compilador, uma vez que ele me devolve um número diferente (e errado) a cada execução

Qual poderia ser o erro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int vetor[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int qtde_impar(int tamanho)
{  int cont;
 int qtde_impar ;

 for (cont = 0 ; cont < 10 ; cont++)
{if (vetor[cont]%2 == 1)
qtde_impar++;
else
continue;}
  return qtde_impar;}



int main()
{
int a ;
a = qtde_impar(10);

printf("%i\n",a);

system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: inicialize `int qtde_impar`, `int qtde_impar = 0` para não pegar lixo de memória.

Comment: Tem o enunciado do exercício? Eu já vi o erro, mas este código pode ser muito melhorado.

Comment: Se o enunciado for esse, ele é ruim, não parece estar completo ou claro. Sua pergunta dá a entender que deseja outra coisa. A primeira coisa para fazer um código correto é interpretar o texto corretamente. Tem que passar o vetor também?

Comment: Valeu, Lucas. Só isso já resolveu meu problema :)

Comment: `else continue` é desnecessário.

Comment: @VictorSouza na verdade tem problemas bem mais sérios. Aquele seria um dos problemas se o exercício fosse contar quantos ímpares tem.

Comment: Outra forma de se escrever `vetor[cont]%2 == 1`, que acredito que seja mais compreensível e simples é `vetor[cont] & 1 == 1`.

Comment: @VictorSouza Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

O algoritmo não faz o que pede o enunciado. Para pegar o maior ímpar deve guardar o maior em variável e atualizá-la sempre que achar um ímpar maior que o que já estava armazenado.

Também fiz a função receber o vetor já que não faz sentido receber o tamanho como parâmetro e o vetor ser acessado globalmente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int qtde_impar(int vetor[], int tamanho) {
    int maior = 1; //precisaria ver se pode ter valores negativos
    for (int cont = 0; cont < 10 ; cont++) if (vetor[cont] % 2 == 1 && vetor[cont] > maior) maior = vetor[cont];
    return maior;
}

int main() {
    int vetor[10] = { 8, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2, 9, 0 };
    printf("%i\n", qtde_impar(vetor, 10));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/6UweKC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hwxhstug-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/GreatestEven.c).

Se puder aceitar negativos, e no momento está aceitando, então deveria começar com o maior [`MIN_INT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) para garantir que comece no menor possível.

O problema "nunca" é no compilador, especialmente alguém que está iniciando não consegue achar um *bug* no compilador. O primeiro passo para conseguir fazer código certo é entender o problema e criar um algoritmo correto. Depois entender cada aspecto da linguagem para saber todas exigências do código.

No caso, se o problema fosse pegar o maior número então a causa é que a variável não era inicializada e pegava um lixo na memória como valor inicial. C não garante segurança de memória, assim ela consegue a melhor performance possível, deixando o programador responsável por cuidar que tudo está dando certo.

Answer (score 2):

Contando quantidade de números impares em um vetor de inteiros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Macro para calcular quantidade de elementos dentro de um vetor */
#define sizeof_vector(_vec) (sizeof(_vec) / sizeof(_vec[0]))

/* Vetores para teste */
int g_vetor_a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int g_vetor_b[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 };
int g_vetor_c[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 };


int contarImpares( int * vet, int qtd )
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0 ; i < qtd ; i++)
        if( vet[i] % 2 )
            n++;

    return n;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    /* Testando */
    printf( "Vetor A: %d\n", contarImpares( g_vetor_a, sizeof_vector(g_vetor_a) ) );
    printf( "Vetor B: %d\n", contarImpares( g_vetor_b, sizeof_vector(g_vetor_b) ) );
    printf( "Vetor C: %d\n", contarImpares( g_vetor_c, sizeof_vector(g_vetor_c) ) );

    return 0;
}


/* fim */
```

Calculando o maior número impar contido em um vetor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Macro para calcular quantidade de elementos dentro de um vetor */
#define sizeof_vector(_vec) (sizeof(_vec) / sizeof(_vec[0]))

/* Vetores para teste */
int g_vetor_a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int g_vetor_b[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 };
int g_vetor_c[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 };


int maiorImpar( int * vet, int qtd )
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = -1;

    for( i = 0 ; i < qtd ; i++)
        if( vet[i] % 2 )
            if( vet[i] > max )
                max = vet[i];

    return max;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    /* Testando */
    printf( "Vetor A: %d\n", maiorImpar( g_vetor_a, sizeof_vector(g_vetor_a) ) );
    printf( "Vetor B: %d\n", maiorImpar( g_vetor_b, sizeof_vector(g_vetor_b) ) );
    printf( "Vetor C: %d\n", maiorImpar( g_vetor_c, sizeof_vector(g_vetor_c) ) );

    return 0;
}

/* fim */
```